# How to solve the "Docker Desktop - WSL kernel version too low" error

Tags: docker, kernel, version, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can I solve the *"Docker Desktop - WSL kernel version too low [Content]"* error?

The rest of the error message:

> Docker Desktop requires a newer WSL kernel version.
>
> Update the WSL kernel by running "wsl --update" or follow instructions at https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel.

[image]

The solution is:

- `wsl --update`

Comment: the question looks fine. Answer was also fine!

Answer (score 47):

I have found this answer. I ran it in the cmd/PowerShell terminal, and it worked for me.

Type `wsl --update` in your terminal to solve the problem.

Comment: the best and the absolute solution